# What's the best use of the translate shortcut in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In a view file:

```
t("example")
```

or

```
t(:example)
```

Comment: how do you define 'best' ? strings are nice because they can contain periods, unlike symbols. Which is a character you'll use often with the translate helper, eg: `t('foo.bar.baz')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing a string can be more succinct. Given a translation file such as:

```
en:
  settings:
    title: 'Settings'
    flash_messages:
      not_saved: 'Setting not saved successfully'
```

You could access the flash messages using a string or symbols:

```
# String
t('settings.flash_messages.not_saved')
# Symbol
t(:not_saved, :scope => [:settings, :flash_messages])
```

Where the `:scope` value is an array containing symbols ordered from top to bottom of the 'namespace tree', if you will.

Both methods lead to the same result, but one, using a string, is arguably easier to use and more readable.

Intuitively I would say the symbol method might be faster (as there might be some regex parsing with the string, which is generally expensive), but I couldn't tell you for certain.